# PHP sequential numbering

Tags: php, numbers, sequence, ranking

I'm having trouble with my page here:

[LINK](http://ds-forums.com/vote/newVote/votes.php)

My "rank" part of the table keeps resetting back to zero when you click on page 2 and beyond. It doesn't start at 21, it just resets back to zero.

How do I fix that?

```
<?php 
include ("database.php");
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
$start_from = ($page-1) * 20; 
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM voting ORDER BY votepoints DESC LIMIT $start_from, 20") or die ("Error 1."); 
$rs_result = mysql_query ($sql) or die (include ("error.html"));
$rank = 1;
?> 
<table>
<tr><td>Rank</td><td></td><td>Username</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>Vote points</td></tr>
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) { 
?> 
            <tr>
            <td><? echo $rank++; ?></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><? echo $row["username"]; ?></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><? echo $row["votepoints"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
<?php 

}; 
?> 
</table>


<?php
echo '<br>';
echo 'Total Votes: ';
include ("sum.php");
include("database.php");

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(votepoints) FROM voting"; 
$rs_result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($rs_result);
$total_records = $row[0];
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / 20);

echo '<span class="text-bleumarin">';
if($page>1)
$pagelink ='<a href="votes.php?page='.($page-1).'">prev</a> ';
echo $pagelink;

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
if ($i != $page)
echo "<a href='votes.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> ";
if ($i==$page)
echo '' . $i . ' ';
};


if($page<$total_pages)
$pagelink ='<a href="votes.php?page='.($page+1).'">next</a> ';
echo $pagelink;
echo '</span>';

?>
```

Comment: another "debug my code for me" question.

Comment: Wasn't a bug, I needed help figuring out how to stop it from resetting to zero. I knew what the problem was, I just didn't know how to fix it. So I asked for help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: this is the line you need to change**
**EDIT2: subtracted 1 from page as you set 1 to default.**

```
<td><? echo (($page-1)*20)+$rank++; ?></td>
```

This will do:

```
(0*20) + 1 = 1
(0*20) + 2 = 2
...
(0*20) + 20 = 20
(1*20) + 1 = 21
(1*20) + 2 = 22
...
(1*20) + 20 = 40
(2*20) + 1 = 41
(2*20) + 2 = 42
...
(2*20) + 20 = 60
...
(21*20) + 1 = 421
```

**Note: No code provided when this solution was posted**

Assuming you are using a for loop of some sort to keep count:

```
if (!isset($_GET['page']))
{
    $page=0;
}
else
{
    $page=$_GET['page'];
}
for($i=1; $i<21; $i++)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.($page*20)+$i.'</td>;' //THIS IS THE RANK LINE
    //Other fields
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: I'd remove your source code, someone gave this question a -1, I removed my source code because whoever it is is having a temper tantrum. I appreciate your help Gazler.